# Hidden Service with Bootstrap 3

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

I was wondering if it is possible to host a hidden service and use Bootstrap (cdn or local) css.

If bootstrap is to big to handle for Tor, is there any other (lightweight) css framework that would be possible to use on a Hidden Service?

Kind regards.

Comment: Tor is agnostic to the content served over it. It shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use whatever CSS framework you want. Tor will happily deliver it. I just tried to open https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/ which is the Onion Service of Facebook. The page had roughly 1.6 MB in size and it took 30 s to load it. Theoretically YouTube could also decide to run a Onion Service and serve videos of that line.

As [@canonizing ironize](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/12737/canonizing-ironize) wrote [in the comment](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15010/hidden-service-with-bootstrap-3#comment16797_15010):

> Tor is agnostic to the content served over it. […]